# Sum of two possible undefined numbers in typescript

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to write a function that returns the sum of two attributes that can also be undefined.
This is what I wrote:

```
type Availability = {
    first: number | undefined
    second: number | undefined
}

function sumPossibleUndefinedValues(availability: Availability): number | undefined {
    const firstNumber = availability.first;
    const secondNumber = availability.second;

    return firstNumber !== undefined || secondNumber !==0
        ? (firstNumber || 0) + (secondNumber || 0)
        : undefined
}
```

Now, I'm wondering if there's a better way to write this return statement.

Comment: A quick search for [default value when undefined](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=javascript+default+value+when+undefined+site%3AStackoverflow.com) will give you plenty of answers to read.

Comment: I don't want to give a default value. Otherwise I always get a number. I want to keep it to undefined if undefined.

Comment: You could replace `(secondNumber !== undefined ? secondNumber : 0)` with `(secondNumber || 0)`, other kind of checks do not seem to make your function simpler.

Comment: I changed it thanks good catch

Answer (score 1):

This is the most easiest I can come up with:

```
type Avaylability = {
    first: number | undefined
    second: number | undefined
}

function sumPossibleUndefinedValues(availability: Avaylability): number | undefined {
    const firstNumber = availability.first; //can be undefined
    const secondNumber = availability.second; //can be undefined

    if (firstNumber === undefined && secondNumber === undefined) return undefined;

    return  (firstNumber ?? 0) + (secondNumber ?? 0);
}
```

Returns the other number if one of them is undefined and returns undefined if both numbers are undefined.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggbgQxAGwQIwJbI6KBeKAbwCgoyoAzDAJwGdgAuKAOwFcBbNCaqAHylbMAJhCrMIQ0uVoQAxgHthTNp258Bw0RnGSAvsWIVBs4BkVRaHAArzatDGmQQAqprESAagmSsItABQIiFjoWDggTPBIqJjYoACUyhxcPPyCIu5CRFJkCsz0lDT0AHLJagRBCCGx4QB0VHTAANxQAPStsgjMUFwaGdoSOVB5BTJ5QqWqPBXBMWGgtWOKQi3tnd296Vo6BuRQGBRQ-g0lZdN4BFuZUABkNxZyy5Mp+Bd92xLxUNQQwKzU3SuAxWu3IPz+ALIxyKwGeagA-PCoAAGL4AaiOS2EcJ4iJR8SaxF0QA)

Comment: The first sum is still giving error at build time as the objects can be undefined.

Comment: What do you mean by error at build time?

Comment: Object is possibly 'undefined'.ts(2532)

Comment: Can you reproduce the error here?: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAZxAWwAp2cmAjAGwFMBVMAEyOBjCPIDUBDAkI5ACkYDdGYDG8fGFACeALkSMwIgJQSw6PEQBOiAD6JwlarXKIA3gChEJxBATIoiasssA5RSsQBeSTz4ChogHQ3LAbkQAeiCIKUQlTQoqGjpjU3MwSxQiRPIHNCVVV25efkECYRFvZFSEckCQsKRIrRjdQ3iTZSIoEGUkPygMrMQAahS0nqc1DS7h1VHB8on-QwBfIA

Comment: [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggbgQxAGwQIwJbI6KBeKAbwCgoyoAzDAJwGdgAuKAOwFcBbNCaqAHylbMAJhCrMIQ0uVoQAxgHthTNp258Bw0RnGSAvsWIVBs4BkVRaHAArzatDGmQQAqprESAagmSsItABQIiFjoWDggTPBIqJjYoACUyhxcPPyCIu5CRFJkCsz0lDT0AHLJagRBCCGx4QB0VHTAANxQAPStsgjMUFwaGdoSOVB5BTJ5QqWqPBXBMWGgtWOKQi3tnd296Vo6BuRQ1BDArNTdDSVlPADUFnLLkyl8-GfA92q8-EvCr9RNxLpAA)

Comment: You can see the error now

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

`return (availability?.first || 0) + (availability?.second || 0)`

Comment: In this way I don't return `undefined` if they're both undefined.

Comment: Yes, by this approach even any of the number is falsy(undefined or null) it'll considered as 0

Comment: Nice workaround ! 